# Grid View for ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid

Are there any build in Grid system for ASP.NET MVC? If there are not, are there package which is friendly for front-end developer beginner?

What I wanted is to press specific button, corresponding elements will be shown and other element will be hidden away in, all this element can only be shown in a Zone reserved for them

Comment: As far as I know,  there's no build in grid system. UI is build up via HTML, thus you can style it via HTML tags. If you want to dynamically change parts of your UI without reloading the page, you're required to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

There is MVC grid which you can get from nuget. Furthermore, you can use JavaScript and partial views with it to complete your requirements. You need to go through its documentation properly. 
Here is the link:
https://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/installation