# How to print out a GridView in C# in ASP.NET MVC view?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, gridview, datatable

I'm struggling a lot trying to figure out how to print out a grid view that I created inside the ASP.NET MVC structure. I created a testing gridview like this:

```cs
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            
dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
dt.Columns.Add("Column2");
dt.Columns.Add("Column3");

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Column1"] = "hello";
dr["Column2"] = "hola";
dr["Column3"] = "hey";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

model.gv.DataSource = dt;
model.gv.DataBind();
```

And now I'm struggling to actually display that gridview inside of my view. I've tried many variations along the lines of:

```cs
@foreach (var item in Model.gv.Rows)
{
    foreach (var row in Model.gv.Columns)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>item</td>
        </tr>
    } 
}
```

This logic of what I have above obviously doesn't make sense at this point but it was just an example of the things I already tried to display something from the gridview.

Does anyone know an easier way to display the rows/columns of a gridview in a tabular format? The hardest part is incorporating the rows and columns with HTML tags with the actual data from the gridview (since my view is using HTML). I appreciate any advice, thanks! :)

Comment: In addition to the answer siddstuff, if you want to chek other alternatives, you might be interested on something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62060797/grid-view-for-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create a model -

public class MyModel..
{
    public string col1 { get; set; }
    public string cal2 { get; set;  }
    public string cal3 { get; set;  }
}


// Store multiple myModel to the myModelList..

MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
List<MyModel> myModelList = new List<MyModel>();

myModel.col1=“hello”;
myModel.col1=“hela”;
myModel.col1=“hey”; 

myModelList.Add(myModel);


 // Pass this myModelList to view ..

foreach(MyModel myModel in myModelList)
{ 
   <tr><td>myModel.col1</td><td>myModel.col2</td><td>myModel.col3</td></tr>
     // Iterate to display .. with single loop.
}
```